# Fastest way of migrating data from EBS to EFS

Tags: amazon-web-services, migration, amazon-ebs, amazon-efs

We have a Nexus server running on Kubernetes with a EBS volume attached to it. The volume has over 13TB of data and as we are running out of space we are thinking to make use of EFS instead of EBS.
I wanted to know is there any fast way to migrate data from EBS to EFS? The ssh tools are very slow and other answers on the internet are for migrating from on-premise to cloud or some other scenarios. Can someone please help me here with this?

Comment: You need to provide more information. What are the "ssh tools" that you're using? How are you running them? What is the actual performance that you're seeing from them? Is your EFS file system in provisioned or burstable mode? If in burstable, how many burst credits do you have?

Comment: Also, if "Nexus" means the Sonatype Nexus Repository Manager, have you considered using [S3 storage](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/high-availability/configuring-blob-stores#ConfiguringBlobStores-AWSSimpleStorageService(S3))? It would be much cheaper, and have effectively infinite storage.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the comment. We are in the initial stage of determining a solution hence we do not have an EFS in place yet. We are looking for options that will be easy for us to migrate data from EBS to any other service.
Yes, we do have Sonatype Nexus but we do not have its license hence cannot use s3.

Comment: In that case, I suggest that you do a prototype to see if there even is a problem.